# How to have a radio button select another radio button's value

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I was wondering if there is a way to make a radio button select another radio buttons data. For example, a "select all" radio button, would select another radio button. Or In the event of a survey where a question could be rated from 0 to 5, when "select all as 0" is selected, all the following radio buttons are selected at "0". 
I feel like there is an easy way of doing this, but I have no Idea what it would be (possibly javascript?) Thanks!

Comment: "Select all" should be a button or a checkbox - but never a radio button.

Comment: Perhaps looping through the array of radiobuttons, checking all of them using Javascript? Just a guess, I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<button type='button' onclick='selectAs0()'>Select All As 0</button>

<input type='radio' name='setA' value='0' /> 0
<input type='radio' name='setA' value='1' /> 1

<input type='radio' name='setB' value='0' /> 0
<input type='radio' name='setB' value='1' /> 1
```

JS

```
function selectAs0() {
  var ALL = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

  for(var x = 0; x< ALL.length;x++) {
    if(ALL[x].type=='radio' && ALL[x].value == 0) {
      ALL[x].checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Untested at this point but should work-ish.

// EDIT

If you're determined to use a radio button to actuate the function, the same concept will 
work...

```
<input type='radio' onclick='selectAs0()' />
```

...but you'll have to add extra code to de-check the radio once it's already selected.

Answer (score 0):

Without doing all the work for you, the basic idea would be to have the "select all 0" button (or checkbox, as ThiefMaster said) with an onchange attribute set to a javascript routine, which then requests document.getElementsByTagName("input"), looping through the returned list and setting the "checked" attribute of the zero-valued radio-buttons. I can elaborate if necessary, but that ought to get you started.