# Button to set/select all RadioButtonFor of a certain value

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I found a similar yet different [question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074171/how-to-have-a-radio-button-select-another-radio-buttons-value) for this which doesn't help me due to the way I made my radio buttons.

```
<%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CDTime, "2")%> N/A
```

If anybody has any ideas how the other linked solution could be adapted to work here or a completely different solution could be used then I'd greatly appreciate it.

Edit - could also do with finding out how to set in a controller the values of a group of radiobuttonfor's based on the value of another radiobuttonfor.

Comment: guess this isn't gonna get an answer, ah well I'll leave it up for a month more then delete it if remains un-answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well I figured out a simple controller way to at least set a bunch of RadioButtonFor values to w/e value wanted but not sure how to get in on a button button but it should work for a radiobutton+dropdownlist+anything else along those lines which has at least 2 different values and I've gone into detail about it in my last comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794917/best-way-to-display-a-group-selection-of-radiobuttons-from-the-choice-of-a-single/4795254#4795254).

Ofc this won't display the change on the page which is what this topic is mainly about but at least for anybody who just needs to know how to achieve the same end result this is a solution.